# Fill Array with null except last index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to find a way to fill an Array with a specific amount of nulls and only replace the last value with a specific number.

My idea would to create an empty Array, set Array.length = desiredLength and set Array[lastElement] = value.
But how to fill the rest?

Example:

Input: Array should have a length of `five` and last value should be `123`

Output: `[null, null, null, null, 123]`

Comment: Maybe `Array(5).fill(null, 0, 4).fill(123, 4, 5)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could `fill` the array with expected length minus 1 elements of `null`, spread that, and finally complemented with the last which is your expected element

Below demo should help you

```js
const length = 5
const lastElem = 123

const res = [...Array(length - 1).fill(null), lastElem]

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
array.fill(null, 0, array.length - 1)
```

And then

```js
array[array.length - 1] = 123
```

Comment: Is `fill` part of `Array` or `Array.prototype`?

Comment: `Array.prototype`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

```js
const arr = new Array(4).fill(null)
arr.push(123)
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Array.from()

```js
const len = 5
const last = 123

const arr = Array.from({ length: len}, (_, i) => i < len - 1 ? null : last)

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also dynamically make a new array using Array.from or Array.apply, and either use the bult in map function for Array.from or call .map after Array.apply

ES6:

```
var filled=Array.from(
    {length: 5}, 
    (x,i, ar) => i < ar.length - 1 ? null : 123
)
```

ES5

```
var filled= Array.apply(0, {length: 5})
    .map(function (x, i, ar) {
        return i < ar.length -1 ? null : 123
    })
```

Comment: @mplungjan what do mean run again, just trying to make everything work in a single expression, are you referring to the .map of the second case,?

Comment: @mplugjan which snippet are you referring to

Comment: @mplugjan I'm taking about in my answer, which part is problematic

Answer (score 0):

use `new Array()` and `Array.fill`

```js
function createNullFilledArray(arrayLength, lastValue) {

  var arr = (new Array(arrayLength)).fill(null, 0, arrayLength - 1);
  arr[arrayLength - 1] = lastValue;
  return arr;
}

var outPut = createNullFilledArray(10, 123);
console.log(outPut);
```